# Package architecture aarch64 does not match system architecture arm64 (dpkg)

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, raspberrypi

On Ubuntu 20.04 for Raspberry Pi LTS edition ... architecture should be aarch64 (that is the correct architecture for the Raspberry Pi 4b, and is what is shown in uname -i output).

I compiled the openboard project from sources on the Raspberry Pi (not cross compiled).  The build and package scripts that are included on Github for this project correctly created an aarch64 debian package, which is now sitting in my home directory waiting to be installed.

However, when I first ran dpkg, it seems to think my architecture is arm64:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/openboard/OpenBoard/install/linux$ sudo dpkg -i openboard_ubuntu_20.04_1.5.4_aarch64.deb 
    dpkg: error processing archive openboard_ubuntu_20.04_1.5.4_aarch64.deb (--install):
     package architecture (aarch64) does not match system (arm64)
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     openboard_ubuntu_20.04_1.5.4_aarch64.deb
```

Note that umake correctly has system as aarch64:

```
qmake -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/openboard/OpenBoard/install/linux$ ls -l
total 23748
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24314184 Sep 15 20:45 openboard_ubuntu_20.04_1.5.4_aarch64.deb
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/openboard/OpenBoard/install/linux$ uname -i
aarch64
```

I tried to add architecture to dpkg but that has royally messed things up:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
```

Now, when I try dpkg it spouts out a bunch of aarch64 dependencies:

```
sudo dpkg -i openboard_ubuntu_20.04_1.5.4_aarch64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package openboard:aarch64.
(Reading database ... 215358 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack openboard_ubuntu_20.04_1.5.4_aarch64.deb ...
Unpacking openboard:aarch64 (1.5.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openboard:aarch64:
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libpaper1 (>= 1.1.28).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libavformat58 (>= 7:4.2.4).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libavcodec58 (>= 7:4.2.4).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libswresample3 (>= 7:4.2.4).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libswscale5 (>= 7:4.2.4).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libavutil56 (>= 7:4.2.4).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.11).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libx11-6 (>= 2:1.6.9).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5webkit5 (>= 5.212.0~).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5svg5 (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5multimediawidgets5 (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5network5 (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5xml5 (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5script5 (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.8).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.31).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 10).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libgomp1 (>= 10).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libgcc-s1 (>= 10).
 openboard:aarch64 depends on onboard.
 openboard:aarch64 depends on libqt5multimedia5-plugins.

dpkg: error processing package openboard:aarch64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openboard:aarch64
```

As you might imagine, all of the packages above that are showing as dependencies are actually installed, and are the latest version.

I am sure I am missing something obvious, but what??

Comment: Just a clarification: As I understand it, arm64 and aarch64 *should* be equivalent (different names for the same architecture), so the initial error generated by dpkg seems to be some kind of bug or configuration issue.

Comment: Same type of situation here. @Jeff Norman, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same issue but thankfully I was able to find a solution.

First, if you check your architecture, you should see the following:

```
$ arch
aarch64
$ uname -m
aarch64
```

If you check `dpkg` you will see that it is actually the root of the problem. It incorrectly thinks that `aarch64` systems are `arm64`:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
arm64
```

If you inspect your Debian package file you can verify that the package correctly shows `aarch64`:

```
$ dpkg --info openboard_ubuntu_20.04_1.5.4_aarch64.deb
...
Architecture: aarch64
```

You were close when you added an architecture, but what you actually need to do is add `aarch64` instead because the system currently believes it is `arm64`:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture aarch64
```

Now you should be able to install your package without issue.